# Remove html tags and split it when end tag was found in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to remove all html tags from the following string and split it without using the period(full stop) as matching character. The following sting is dynamic one which can have more conditions inside list tag

```
<li>This Offer cannot be redeemed with any other offer.</li><li>Only one Offer can be used at a time.</li><li>This Offer is not transferable.</li><li>......</li><li>....</li</ul></div>
```

I'm Expecting the following relult

1. This Offer cannot be redeemed with any other offer.
2. Only one Offer can be used at a time.
3. This Offer is not transferable.
4. ....
5. ....

Comment: first show us what you have done dude. we here help to solve your issues, not give some readymade solution that you just copy paste and say eureka!

Comment: I removed html tags, but i want it to be splited.
return Regex.Replace(inputString, "<.*?>", string.Empty);

Comment: please edit your questionand also write expected result

Comment: dont remove all the tags, build a regex to remove all the tags except </li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] myString = yourString.replace("<li>", "").Split(new string[] { "</li>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

try this

```
const string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<[^/li]>"; // may require some change
string safeString = Regex.Replace(yourString, HTML_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty);
String[] myString = safeString.Split(new string[] { "</li>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

you can try this regex too

```
string acceptable = "li";
string stringPattern = @"</?(?(?=" + acceptable + @")notag|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+=?(?:(["",']?).*?\1?)?)*\s*/?>";
string yourString= Regex.Replace(yourString, stringPattern, string.Empty);
String[] myString = yourString.replace("<li>", "").Split(new string[] { "</li>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove all html tag and split also by below code

```
string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<.*?>";
string str = @"<li>This Offer cannot be redeemed with any other offer.</li><li>Only one Offer can be used at a time.</li><li>This Offer is not transferable.</li><li>......</li><li>....</li</ul></div>";
string[] stString = Regex.Replace(str.Replace("</li>", "#$#"), HTML_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty).Split("#$#".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: that what his q is, if he removes all the tags by this regex then how can he split it, based on what parameters?

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to give id to your `<li>` then ,
You can try with javascript code something like following>>

```
var str=doccument.getElementById("liID").innerHTML;
```

This thing you can try on windows onload event or any specific according to your application.

Comment: the answer is not quite related to windows phone